# Java 8 to Java 11: package com.sun.jndi.ldap is not visible

Tags: java, java-8, ldap, package, java-11

After moving from Java8 to Java11, I'm getting the error "package com.sun.jndi.ldap is not visible". But I need this package for the Class LdapCtxFactory. Is the package moved or should I use another Class for my Ldap-Connection?

Best regards

Comment: It very fragile to depend on undocumented/JDK-internal classes. Why do you need to use LdapCtxFactory directly?

Comment: I put it in my properties for ldap connection:
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, LdapCtxFactory.class.getName());

Comment: If that’s your only use, why don’t you replace `LdapCtxFactory.class.getName()` with `"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"`?

Comment: @Holger, why not add that as an answer so that it can be accepted?

Comment: @Jaywalker I wasn’t sure whether this a solution for the OP. Since it’s acknowledged now, I converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your only use of the class `LdapCtxFactory` is a configuration setup as

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, LdapCtxFactory.class.getName());
```

you can remove the dependency to the class by replacing `LdapCtxFactory.class.getName()` with the qualified name `"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"`, i.e.

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
```